# AngularJs and Codeigniter routing causes infinite redirection loop

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, angularjs

I'm using angularJs1.2 with codeigniter PHP frame work. i'm using angularJS routing feature as the following:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ngRoute']).config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/profile/personalInfo', {templateUrl: '<?php echo base_url().'profile/personalInfo' ?>', controller: personalInfo});
        $routeProvider.when('/profile/myPlaces', {templateUrl: '<?php echo base_url().'profile/myPlaces' ?>', controller: myPlaces});
        $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }]);
```

as you see, `templateUrl` loaded by a codeigniter path like `base_url().'profile/personalInfo'`. But the user can access the partial page directly through this path and i don't want this, so i used codeiginter routing to prevent accessing the partial pages directly like this:

```
$route['profile/(:any)'] = 'profile/index/$1';
```

but when i set codeigniter routing the page go to infinite redirection loop inside angular itself not the hole page. When i remove codeiginter routing it works fine, but my partial pages can be accessed also.
How i can solve this problem?

Comment: have you considered delivering partials from another controller?

Comment: I cann't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, the problem is the routing of the codeigniter and angularjs are the same and this causes the problem. In my example angularjs routing was `/profile/personalInfo` and also codeigniter routing was `$route['profile/(:any)']` and this caused the loop, when i changed angularjs routing to `/user/personalInfo` its worked fine.